# Как узнать JS событие и вызвать его в коде?

Tags: javascript

Существует элемент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Его код

```
<div class="inline-block">
  <span class="callback-block animate-load twosmallfont colored" data-event="jqm" data-param-id="19" data-name="callback">Заказать звонок</span>
</div>
```

По нажатию на элемент открывается всплывающая форма
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу узнать выполняемое событие по клику. Как я могу вызвать это событие из кода?

Comment: Ну посмотрите в JS коде где это событие, возможно событие на callback-block должно быть

Comment: Это давольно большой сайт, с большим количеством файлов скриптов

Comment: Возможно chrome devtools поможет, выделить элемент, и посмотреть event listeners.

Comment: Если вам надо просто вызвать событие а не искать искомый код, можете  попробовать повесить событие т.е click() на callback-block

Comment: В Mozilla в консоли висят значки событий, которые имеет тот или иной элемент, там можно все посмотреть.

Comment: В зависимости от js кода могут быть различные варианты поиска. Думаю реальная страница тут помогла бы больше чем просто html код. Я обычно включаю остановку в случае изменения атрибутов элементов (break on attributes modifications) в дереве элементов в инструментах для разработчика. Как только поймете как запускается, можно так же вызвать. Это может быть что-то вроде $(elem).click()

Comment: `@NeedHate` действительно, раньше такого не замечал. Очень удобно, спасибо!   `@holden321` получилось вызвать `$("div.phone-block div.inline-block span").click()`. Оформите, пожалуйста, ответ

Answer (score 0):

Для определения обработчиков событий удобно пользоваться Chrome DevTools -> Sources> EventListener BreakPoints.
В данном случае, нужно выбрать "click" и кликнуть по исследуемому элементу

[image: Chrome DevTools. Event Listener Breakpoint]

Comment: Мне кажется неоднозначный какой-то ответ. Так и не смог отследить именно моё событие. Вариант с Mozilla пока более оптимальный

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, что это и есть ответ на Ваш вопрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ находится на qaru.

Код:

```
$(document).click(function(event){
  // event.target is the clicked object
});



$(document).click(function(event){
  $(event.target).closest(".clickable").each(function(){
    // "this" is your "clickable" clicked
  });
});
```

Comment: ответы на qaru это переводы ответов на so :-)

Comment: @Grundy, круг замкнулся)